# Twilio Video Call - Battery drops very fast (1% per about one second) and device is very hot after 10 minutes

Tags: ios, video, twilio, phone-call, battery

I am using Twilio's Programmable Video sdk for iOS video calling app.
The video calling works well, but I face the this issue when I have a long time video call.
I used full screen mode for iOS devices. so In the Video constraint options, I setup 16:9 aspect ratio video dimension and try to add a frame per second with 10 fps to saving battery.

This is the objective-c code for Video constraints:

```
    TVIVideoConstraints *videoConstraints = [TVIVideoConstraints constraintsWithBlock:
^(TVIVideoConstraintsBuilder * _Nonnull builder) {
builder.maxSize = TVIVideoConstraintsSize960x540;
builder.minSize = TVIVideoConstraintsSize960x540;
builder.minFrameRate = TVIVideoConstraintsFrameRate10;
builder.maxFrameRate = TVIVideoConstraintsFrameRate10;
}];
self.localVideoTrack = [TVILocalVideoTrack trackWithCapturer:self.camera enabled:YES constraints:videoConstraints];
```

But Battery % drops 1% per second, and very hot from 10 min call and more.
Btw, Video quality is too good rather than WhatsApp video call.

Is there any solution for implementing the long time video call?
Please help me.

Video iOS SDK
Installed from the latest cocoapods

Xcode9.2/iOS 11.2.5

Comment: Hey there, I'm a developer evangelist from Twilio. I'm a little confused, if the battery is dropping by 1% per second, then the phone wouldn't last longer than 100 seconds, less than 2 minutes, but you're talking about 10 minute calls. I find that battery life can be severely affected by the signal my phone has when it is using the network. What is the network connection like when you make these test calls?

Comment: Thank you for response Philnash, 
Sorry. battery drops about 1% per minute. is there any relationship between the battery life & heat and frame rate(fps) or bit rate(bps) of a video call ?

Comment: Like I said, my phone gets hot and uses battery when it uses the network a lot (more so if it has a weak network connection). I do not know if there is a relationship between that and the frame/bit rate of the call. It might be best for you to find more devices to test on too. Still, video calling does use features of the device that will use a lot of energy. Reading information from the camera and microphone, streaming that data and receiving streaming data and displaying video and playing live audio is quite a lot. Plus whatever else your application does.